# django session store has not attribute

Tags: python, django, eclipse

django 1.5

I have a eclipse windows development setup and a Linux Apache host.

I have to pull some user data from a WSDL. When I do this from eclipse it works like a charm but when I update the code on the Linux server I get an error message. `'sessionstore' object has no attribute 'type'`

```
 if result.opError != None:
    pass
    #do something to deal with this error IDk what.
 else:
    request.session['sID'] = result.opSessionID
    request.session['role'] = result.opRole.upper()
    request.session['type'] = result.opUserType.upper()
```

I have used the `request.session['<name>']` in several places and never had an issue. I have tried `clearsesions` data and syncing the DB.

How do I get it to take the new session data?

Thanks

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://xxxx.com:8080/login/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'users',
 'WorkOrder',
 'Equipment')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/www/Django/Test/users/views.py" in login_user
  102.              request.session['type'] = result.opUserType.upper()         

Exception Type: AttributeError at /login/
Exception Value: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute 'role'
```

Comment: That code wouldn't throw that error. Can you please show the full traceback?

Comment: I think you should be using result.user to get access to those attribute, have tried that?

Comment: yes, that doesn't work. 'User' object does not support item assignment